# ImportError: no module named 'mpu9250'

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I try to connect a IMU (MPU-9250) using the Raspberry Pi Pico W with Pyhton (MicroPython) and I wrote the code in VSC.

But when I try to pass the code to the microcontroller the system says **ImportError: no module named 'mpu9250'**
I used pip to install the oficial module: https://pypi.org/project/micropython-mpu9250/

```
from machine import Pin, Timer,I2C
from math import sqrt, atan2, pi, copysign, sin, cos
from mpu9250 import MPU9250


i2c = I2C(id=0, scl=Pin(1), sda=Pin(0)) # type: ignore
sensor = MPU9250(i2c)
print("MPU9250 id: " + hex(sensor.whoami))
```

According with the page this is the correct way to call the import

I am expecting that the code compiles and conects me with the IMU.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you installed the module in your local python instead of the pi?